# How to compare xaml page versus e.OriginalSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events, routedeventargs

I have a method that looks like below:

```
private void someEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.OriginalSource == typeof(a.b.c.somePages))
}
```

This method will be in my viewModel. From breakpoint, I can see there is this e.OriginalSource which has my xaml page `somePages` as value. Hence I'm trying to compare the value. But it's giving me warning as below:

```
Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, 
cast the left hand side to type 'System.Type'
```

So I updated my code to `if((System.Type)e.OriginalSource == typeof(a.b.c.somePages))` but the warning is still there. May I know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, you need to type cast. You can not get the type of an object without a cast because for `e.OriginalSource` type will be `Object`. Besides, in the construction [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) is to be an object of `System.Type` type:

> Used to obtain the `System.Type` object for a *type*.

Therefore try this:

```
Page page = e.OriginalSource as Page;

if (page != null) 
{
    string test = page.ToString();
}
```

Or just use `ToString()` method for `e.OriginalSource` like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the correct way but I able to compare using the following way:

```
if(e.OriginalSource.ToString() == "a.b.c.SomePages")
```

Answer (score 1):

You were comparing an object to `type`. If you intended to compare type of the object instead, try to do it this way :

```
if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(a.b.c.somePages))
{

}
```

Another way is using [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator :

```
if(e.OriginalSource is a.b.c.SomePages)
{

}
```

From MSDN link above, about `is` :

> "Checks if an object is compatible with a given type".